# jQuery delegate mouseover mouseout event is not triggering on first mouseover

Tags: jquery

If I mouseover and mouseout .activate_tooltip once, it continues to work thereafter.  But the first mouseover does not trigger any action.  Anyone know what causes this?

```
$('.task_box').delegate('.activate_tooltip', 'mouseover mouseout', function(event) { 

             if (event.type == 'mouseover') {

                  clearTimeout(timeOut);
                  $(this).prev().find('.tooltip_2').show();

             } else if (event.type == "mouseout") {

                 timeOut = setTimeout(hideToolTip, 0);

             }    

});



<div class="edit_task_icon_div" style="position:relative;">

    <div style="position:relative">
        <div class="tooltip_2" style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: -6px;">
            <div class="tooltip_2_text">Edit</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a href="#" id="edit_{{task.id}}" class="pencil_button activate_tooltip"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  The clearTimeout was causing the issue for some reason.  It worked when I used the .hover event, but commenting it out in the delegate seemed to fix the problem.  Not sure why!

Answer (score 0):

Change this `event.type="mouseout"` to `event.type=='mouseout'`

Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`

Comment: Whoops, overlooked that.  Still didn't fix the problem though.

Comment: @ThinkingInBits: Use mouseenter and mouseleave, instead of mouseover and mouseout

Comment: Same problem with mouseenter and mouseleave

Comment: @ThinkingInBits: can you post your html?